# Login and sign up page using asp.net, not receiving input

Tags: asp.net

I'm not very knowledgeable about coding and I only started a bit ago so there are likely multiple mistakes here that I'm not aware of and would appreciate help with that aswell if you see any.

I've been trying for a while now to understand the reason this is not working and came to the conclusion that it doesn't receive the input at all.
How I came to that conclusion:
I did 3 things to check it, first instead of requesting the input, I just set a specific thing to see if it adds it to the database, it did. Second instead of an input, I decided to set again a specific thing I set ahead of time to see if it takes it using the same method, it did. Third was something I should've done since the start, it was to check what was being sent, I took all restrictions off what goes into the DB, and realized everything went in empty.

The code:

```
<h1> Sign Up</h1>
    <p>
        <label>Phone number </label>
        <input type="text" runat="server" id="phoneT"  name="phoneT" title="Must be 10 digits" pattern="[0-9]{10}"/>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Name </label>
        <input type="text" runat="server" id="nameT" name="nameT"/>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Email </label>
        <input type="text" runat="server" id="emailT" name="emailT"/>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Password </label>
        <input type="password" runat="server" id="pwdT" name="pwdT"/>
    </p>
    <p>
        <button type="button" runat="server" onclick="hey()" >Hey</button>
        <button type="button" runat="server" onserverclick="SignUp1">Send</button>
        <button type="button" runat="server" onclick="Clear()">Clear</button>

    </p>
```

protected void SignUp1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

```
        Person temp = new Person
        {
            Phone = Request["phoneT"].ToString(),
            Name = Request["nameT"].ToString(),
            Email = Request["emailT"].ToString(),
            pwd = Request["pwdT"].ToString(),
            Auth = "1"
        };
        int answer = myDB.Insert(temp);
        if (answer == 0)
        {
            message.InnerText = "Can't add you";
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
        }
       
    }
```

Comment: Not sure why you using Request here? In your code you can/should be able to use namtT.Value to get at that control in code behind.

Comment: Still get the same exact problem, it returns nothing.

Comment: @idiotgrr Is the HTML markup inside the form tag ?

Comment: @Arib Yousuf If I do understand your question correctly.. then I don't have a form tag.

Comment: @idiotgrr Enclose all your html in form tag with runat="server" attribute on it. It will work

Comment: @AribYousuf It's a master page, cant use another form with runat="server